# Variance of roots of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a polynomial $p(z)=\sum _0^na_iz^n$, where $a_i \in C,$ set of complex numbers. Is it possible to find the variance or some sharp estimate of it, of roots in the following sense:$$\operatorname{var}(roots)=\sigma^2=\sum|z_i-z_{av}|^2/n,$$ where $z_i$ are the roots and $z_{av}$ is the complex average of other roots, which is $\frac{-a_{n-1}}{na_n}?$
I have no idea how much this problems has been studied but I feel this is very interesting and difficult as well. To make some start one might start with: $$ \sigma^2=\sum (z_i-m)(\overline{z_i}-\overline{m})/n=\sum(|z_i|^2+|m|^2-\overline{z_i}m-\overline{m}z_i)/n$$ where,$$m=z_{av}.$$

Is it possible to produce an estimate from the above?

Answer (score 3):

Using [Viete sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), you can often (maybe always?) easily write symmetric functions of the roots of a polynomial in terms of the coefficients. As you have noted, the sum of the roots is $-a_{n-1}/a_n$. So we can `depress' a polynomial by shifting each root by the average. Namely, substituting $$z=w-\frac{a_{n-1}}{na_n}$$ will make a polynomial $p(w)=\sum_0^nb_iw^i$ with $b_{n-1}=0$. Then, the variance $\sigma^2$ is the average square of the roots. Using the identity

$$(w_1+\dots+w_n)^2=w_1^2+\dots w_n^2+2(w_1w_2+w_1w_3\dots+
w_{n-1}w_n)$$

and the Viete sum for the sum of roots taken two at a time,

$$0=n\sigma^2+2\frac{b_{n-2}}{b_n}$$

giving $$\sigma^2=-\frac{2b_{n-2}}{nb_n}$$

for depressed polynomials, $b_{n-1}=0$. To get the general formula, we back substitute.

\begin{align*}
b_n=& a_n\\
b_{n-1}=& 0\\
b_{n-2}=& a_n{n\choose 2}\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{na_n}\right)^2-a_{n-1}(n-1)\frac{a_{n-1}}{na_n}+a_{n-2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Note, for the complex coefficient case, this argument fails upon $|w_1+\dots+w_n|^2=|w_1|^2+\dots+|w_n|^2+2\mathcal{Re}(w_1\overline{w_2}+\dots+w_{n-1}\overline{w_n})$ while the Viete sums remain unchanged.