# Variance of roots

Tags: probability, complex-numbers

Consider a polynomial $p(z)=\sum _0^na_iz^n$, where $a_i \in C,$ set of complex numbers. Is it possible to find the variance or some sharp estimate of it, of roots in the following sense:$$\operatorname{var}(roots)=\sigma^2=\sum|z_i-z_{av}|^2/n,$$ where $z_i$ are the roots and $z_{av}$ is the complex average of other roots, which is $\frac{-a_{n-1}}{na_n}?$
I have no idea how much this problems has been studied but I feel this is very interesting and difficult as well. To make some start one might start with: $$ \sigma^2=\sum (z_i-m)(\overline{z_i}-\overline{m})/n=\sum(|z_i|^2+|m|^2-\overline{z_i}m-\overline{m}z_i)/n$$ where,$$m=z_{av}.$$

Is it possible to produce an estimate from the above?

Comment: Why not just compute the desired value directly? Are you looking for an algorithm that operates directly on the coefficients instead of finding the roots? Is there a runtime requirement?

Comment: Related: [geometrical properties of polynomial roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_.28complex.29_polynomial_roots)

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605513/variance-of-roots-of-a-polynomial